# Kivy Label Markup link change

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, hyperlink, label, kivy

I have been looking into making a link in a label using markup, I have done this but was wondering if there is a way to change the url to which the link points

If I have

```
Label:
    id: sLinksLabel
    text: 'Load Up [ref=some]some_link[/ref]'
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.20}
    size: (150, 44)
    markup: True
    on_ref_press:
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open("somelink.com")
```

is it then posible to have that link change when the text in the label gets changed to a link?

i.e if the label text changes, something like

```
self.root.sLinks.text = '[ref=some]some_other_link[/ref]'
```

I also thought about calling a procedure like

```
def loadlink(self, *args):
    if sLinks.text == 'Load Up [ref=some]website[/ref]': #check if nothing has changed load default page
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open("some_link")
    else: #text has been changed load new link
        link = self.root.sLinks.text #get link from label text
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(some_other_link)
```

and changing the on_ref_press to

```
        on_ref_press:
        loadlink()
```

but it says loadlink is not defined... grrrr

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`on_ref_press` provides you with the reference id as `args[1]`, so you could use that:

```
Label:
    id: sLinksLabel
    text: 'Load Up [ref=http://google.com]some_link[/ref]'
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.20}
    size: (150, 44)
    markup: True
    on_ref_press:
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(args[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i understand, so create mulitple refs and the args help you select particular ones? is that right?! if so, i cant really use that as the links i get change so i could literally have an infinite number or links. I'm looking at news articles and displaying the urls then when they get clicked on i want to open it...

Comment: You stated in your question that you would change the text elsewhere. If you change the text in the `Label`, then you can easily change the ref id at the same time.

Comment: That sounds great! but I cant find a way to reference the labels text in the builder load string,([ref=self.root.sLinks.text] Link [/ref]) I can't find a document with arg[1] referencing the text inside a label, could you point me in the right direction re documentation or give an example please? I've tried http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html and searching for args[1] within but can find anything that will explain it to my feeble brain!

Comment: Assuming the kv is an excerpt from your app's kv file, and this `Label` is part of the root widget rule, then you can use `self.root.ids.sLinksLabel.text = '...'` from your App class or `App.get_running_app().root.ids.sLinksLabel.text = '...'` elsewhere. As for `args` - every event has arguments. The first argument is always the `EventDispatcher` instance (i.e. a `Widget`), and the rest of the arguments vary based on the event. The `on_ref_press` event sends a total of two arguments: the `Label` instance (`args[0]`), and the reference id (`args[1]`).

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i've been ill. Thanks for sticking with me! Not sure if I understand or if I have made myself clear. When you set the label up in the kv build string i can call the main webpage from there easily using the above code. However I want to display the url of an article based on a keyword (ie Dartmouth) so a new url is going to be generated daily. I get the url displayed in the label but the markup has disapeared from the original instance created in the build string. Is there a way, when I display the string in the label to redo the markup ref for the new url on_press?

Comment: You just need to replace the entire string, like `self.root.ids.sLinksLabel.text = 'Load Up [ref=http://stackoverflow.com]another link[/ref]'`

Comment: the markup works, the probelm i jave is that the url is held in a string called 'link' and if i try and put that into it... i.e. self.root.ids.sLinksLabel.text = 'Load Up [ref=link]Direct link[/ref]' its not the url that gets loaded but the word link lol. sorry if it is a newbie question or just a bit daft but i'm not sure it can be done. all my searches bring up answers like yours, with the url directly entered and not referenced in a string. Any ideas? @Ryan P

Comment: `self.root.ids.sLinksLabel.text = 'Load Up [ref=' + link + ']Direct link[/ref]'`

Comment: Thanks so much!! i knew i was being daft!! i left out the + either side of the quotation marks while messing with the line of code!! again thank you!!